# Open Multiple Links in One Action Javascript/Jquery (not Popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open multiple url on a single event/click which would also go to the url I specify
I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work.

html

```
<a id="mybutton" href="http://example.net/quote" onclick="url_open()">See Offer</a>
```

Script

```
function url_open() {
    window.open("http://example.net/events","_blank");
    window.open("http://example.net/gallery","_blank");
    alert('Check The Tabs');
}
```

What I am trying to do is send the user to quote page upon clicking the button while opening two tabs at the same time

P.S.
Two tabs get opened in Firefox and IE but not on Chrome

Comment: This should work if you do not have a popup blocker

Comment: I do not have a popup block and tested it using private window but didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Browsers have built-in pop-up blockers, so you can open one URL at the page u are currently on and one in the new tab. 
Try:

```
function url_open() {
    window.open("http://example.net/events",'_top');
    window.open("http://example.net/gallery",'_blank');
    alert('Check The Tabs');
}
```